# How to make this multiple if statement work?

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

See photo attached. I am trying to create a grid with commas separating each horse from each race by their grades. Formula I am using is:

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(AND(race=$F$5,grade=G$4),horse,""))

I am getting a false (blank results) in the AND statement. Where am I going wrong?

Excel Look:

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 2):

If you have office 365 use FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(horse,(race=$F$5)*(grade=G$4),""))
```

If Excel 2019 then:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((race=$F$5)*(grade=G$4),horse,""))
```

Array formula do not like AND as it will return a single response and not an array.  So we multiply for AND and add for OR.